# Changing the length of a custom object name field

Tags: ide, custom-object

Again, new to Salesforce, trying to do good things for good people.  I have inherited a custom object with a data type of 'text' and it seems to be limited to 40 characters.  Is there a way to expand that field length to 255?  I've brought the object down to the IDE and have added the attribute to the length, but when I try to reload it back to SF, it disappears like I never typed it.  Here's what it looks like in the IDE:
[image: custom object code]

Thanks!

Comment: If it is just about changing the length of a text field of an object, cant you do it directly in SF?

Comment: @RichardN Yes, probably, but since I pulled everything into the IDE it was what I was working in at the time.

Comment: Based on the responses received, I find this aspect of SF to be very frustrating.  I know I've seen the place to make requests on the developer site, but does anyone know where to find it offhand?  I may as well file this along with my other situations with no known solution.

Comment: Vote for this idea if you would like to see this enhanced in a future release:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kowTAAQ

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your screen shot is a field "Name Field" for a custom object. If i remember right, it is limited to 80 characters which cannot be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the length of the standard "Name" field on a custom object.